# How to use function with more than 1 parameter in multiprocessing?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So, I'm new in multiprocessing in Python. What I want is to run function in parallel. Here is my code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool,cpu_count

def f(x,y): return x*y

if __name__=='__main__':
    A=input('Input list: ')
    n=input('Input multiplier: ')
    def g(x): return f(x,y=n)
    p=Pool(cpu_count())
    result=p.map(g,A)
    print result
```

But, it shows this error when I tried to run it:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'g'
```

What did I do wrong? Is there any way to prevent this? Because if I do this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool,cpu_count

A=input('Input list: ')
n=input('Input multiplier: ')

def f(x,y=n): return x*y

if __name__=='__main__':
    p=Pool(cpu_count())
    result=p.map(g,A)
    print result
```

It show this error:

```
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: use functools.partial to achieve that

Comment: `p=Pool(cpu_count()` needs a closing parenthesis.

Comment: @vks Thank you very much! That's what I need.... ^^

Comment: @DYZ Oh, I mistype it. I'll fix it. In my actual code it has closing parenthesis.